# How to send multiple attachments in single email using SendGrid Api?

Tags: android, sendgrid-api-v3

I was able to send email with single attachment but I cannot find anything for sending multiple attachments in a single mail

```
        try {
            SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid(SENDGRID_USERNAME, SENDGRID_PASSWORD);

            SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();

            // Get values from edit text to compose email
            // TODO: Validate edit texts
            email.addTo(mTo);
            email.setFrom(mFrom);
            email.setSubject(mSubject);
            email.setText(mText);

            // Attach image
            if (mUri != null) {
                email.addAttachment(mAttachmentName, mAppContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri));
            }

            // Send email, execute http request
            SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
            mMsgResponse = response.getMessage();

            Log.d("SendAppExample", mMsgResponse);

        } catch (SendGridException | IOException e) {
            Log.e("SendAppExample", e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You can simply call addAttachment() in the same manner for adding a single file. I accomplished this with a foreach, based on an array of file paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = ['/home/pawr/testAttach1.txt','/home/pawr/testAttach2.txt'];
foreach($files as $f) {
    // create attachment and add to email
    $fn = $this->createSendGridAttachment($f);
    $email->addAttachment($fn);
}
// code in custom function createSendGridAttachment($file_path)
{
    // Note, you may need to use different encoding methods for setContent() and
    // MIME types with setType() depending on your use case.
    $content = file_get_contents($file_path);
    $content = base64_encode($content);
    $attachment = new \SendGrid\Mail\Attachment();
    $attachment->setContent($content);
    $attachment->setFilename(basename($file_path));

    return $attachment;
}
```

Comment: Actually, its an android tagged question. Thanks anyway @Pawr

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan, my mistake!